# How do I show a tooltip on top of a parent container with the tailwind class overflow-x-scroll applied?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to show a tooltip when I hover over a square. This square is positioned within a parent container that needs to have the `overflow-x-scroll` class applied. The problem I am encountering is that when I hover over this square, the tooltip shows but is cut off due to the parent class having the `overflow-x-scroll` class applied. I tried messing with the `z-index,` but that did not help. I also tried messing around with the `overflow-y-visible` class; however, that was also a no-go.

For better or worse I am unable to just change the height of the parent container otherwise I would have done that.

Link to tailwind playground: https://play.tailwindcss.com/Mb5XO1DTZs

HTML:

```
<div class="mx-auto max-w-6xl p-8">

  <div id="grid" class="grid grid-rows-7 gap-2 grid-flow-col p-4 bg-red-300 rounded-md shadow-md overflow-x-scroll">

    <div id="gridItem" class="relative cursor-pointer items-center bg-gray-500 shadow-md rounded-[2px] h-3 w-3 text-xs hover:z-50" data-tooltip="LOOK HERE">
    </div>
    
    <div id="gridItem" class="relative cursor-pointer items-center bg-gray-500 shadow-md rounded-[2px] h-3 w-3 text-xs hover:z-50" data-tooltip="LOOK HERE">
    </div>

    <div id="gridItem" class="relative cursor-pointer items-center bg-gray-500 shadow-md rounded-[2px] h-3 w-3 text-xs hover:z-50" data-tooltip="LOOK HERE">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

CSS file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

#gridItem::before,
#gridItem::after {
  --scale: 0;
  --arrow-size: 5px;
  --tooltip-color: green;

  position: absolute;
  top: -.25rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(var(--translate-y, 0)) scale(var(--scale));
  transition: 150ms transform;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}


#gridItem::before {
  --translate-y: calc(-100% - var(--arrow-size));

  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  color: white;
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: .3rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: max-content;
  background: var(--tooltip-color);
}

#gridItem:hover::before,
#gridItem:hover::after {
  --scale: 1;
  z-index: 50;
  visibility: visible;
  overflow: visible;
}

#gridItem::after {
  --translate-y: calc(-1 * var(--arrow-size));

  content: '';
  border: var(--arrow-size) solid transparent;
  border-top-color: var(--tooltip-color);
  transform-origin: top center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to have the tooltip elements outside the element with `overflow-x-scroll`.

For example:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<div class="relative mx-auto max-w-6xl p-8 [--arrow-size:5px] [--tooltip-color:green]">
  <div id="grid" class="grid-rows-7 grid grid-flow-col gap-2 overflow-x-scroll rounded-md bg-red-300 p-4 shadow-md">
    <div id="gridItem" class="relative h-3 w-3 cursor-pointer items-center rounded-[2px] bg-gray-500 text-xs shadow-md hover:z-50" data-tooltip="LOOK HERE"></div>

    <div id="gridItem" class="relative h-3 w-3 cursor-pointer items-center rounded-[2px] bg-gray-500 text-xs shadow-md hover:z-50" data-tooltip="LOOK HERE"></div>

    <div id="gridItem" class="relative h-3 w-3 cursor-pointer items-center rounded-[2px] bg-gray-500 text-xs shadow-md hover:z-50" data-tooltip="LOOK HERE"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="absolute left-[calc(theme(padding.8)+theme(padding.4)+(theme(width.3)/2))] top-[calc(theme(padding.8)+theme(padding.4)-.25rem)] w-max origin-bottom -translate-x-1/2 translate-y-[calc(-100%-var(--arrow-size))] rounded-[.3rem] bg-[--tooltip-color] p-2 text-center text-xs text-white transition-transform scale-0 [#grid:has(#gridItem:nth-child(1):hover)~&]:scale-100">LOOK HERE</div>
  <div class="absolute left-[calc(theme(padding.8)+theme(padding.4)+(theme(width.3)/2))] top-[calc(theme(padding.8)+theme(padding.4)-.25rem)] w-max origin-top -translate-x-1/2 translate-y-[calc(-1*var(--arrow-size))] border-[length:--arrow-size] border-transparent border-t-[--tooltip-color] transition-transform scale-0 [#grid:has(#gridItem:nth-child(1):hover)~&]:scale-100"></div>

  <div class="absolute left-[calc(theme(padding.8)+theme(padding.4)+((100%-(theme(padding.4)*2)-(theme(padding.8)*2)-(theme(gap.2)*2))/3)+theme(gap.2)+(theme(width.3)/2))] top-[calc(theme(padding.8)+theme(padding.4)-.25rem)] w-max origin-bottom -translate-x-1/2 translate-y-[calc(-100%-var(--arrow-size))] rounded-[.3rem] bg-[--tooltip-color] p-2 text-center text-xs text-white transition-transform scale-0 [#grid:has(#gridItem:nth-child(2):hover)~&]:scale-100">LOOK HERE</div>
  <div class="absolute left-[calc(theme(padding.8)+theme(padding.4)+((100%-(theme(padding.4)*2)-(theme(padding.8)*2)-(theme(gap.2)*2))/3)+theme(gap.2)+(theme(width.3)/2))] top-[calc(theme(padding.8)+theme(padding.4)-.25rem)] w-max origin-top -translate-x-1/2 translate-y-[calc(-1*var(--arrow-size))] border-[length:--arrow-size] border-transparent border-t-[--tooltip-color] transition-transform scale-0 [#grid:has(#gridItem:nth-child(2):hover)~&]:scale-100"></div>

  <div class="absolute left-[calc(theme(padding.8)+theme(padding.4)+((100%-(theme(padding.4)*2)-(theme(padding.8)*2)-(theme(gap.2)*2))*2/3)+(theme(gap.2)*2)+(theme(width.3)/2))] top-[calc(theme(padding.8)+theme(padding.4)-.25rem)] w-max origin-bottom -translate-x-1/2 translate-y-[calc(-100%-var(--arrow-size))] rounded-[.3rem] bg-[--tooltip-color] p-2 text-center text-xs text-white transition-transform scale-0 [#grid:has(#gridItem:nth-child(3):hover)~&]:scale-100">LOOK HERE</div>
  <div class="absolute left-[calc(theme(padding.8)+theme(padding.4)+((100%-(theme(padding.4)*2)-(theme(padding.8)*2)-(theme(gap.2)*2))*2/3)+(theme(gap.2)*2)+(theme(width.3)/2))] top-[calc(theme(padding.8)+theme(padding.4)-.25rem)] w-max origin-top -translate-x-1/2 translate-y-[calc(-1*var(--arrow-size))] border-[length:--arrow-size] border-transparent border-t-[--tooltip-color] transition-transform scale-0 [#grid:has(#gridItem:nth-child(3):hover)~&]:scale-100"></div>
</div>
```

This is a minimal example of it working, with some known caveats:

- The positioning of the tooltips are brittle. You'd probably want to use JavaScript to ensure the tooltips are positioned correctly with respect to their elements.
- You'd want to consider the accessibility of the tooltips, i.e. [WCAG 2.2 1.4.13](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG22/#content-on-hover-or-focus) for example.
- The tooltip content is no longer linked to their parent's `data-tooltip` element. Again, you'd probably want to use JavaScript to keep them in sync.
- This example uses [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) which is fairly new with regards to browser support and not currently in Firefox stable channel. You could consider using JavaScript as an alternative.